# Factorize into irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Trying to factorize the following polynomial into irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$:

$$f(x) = 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x - 1.$$

So this factorizes into $(3x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$ where $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible but I'm not sure what to do with $3x-1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by 'What to do...'? You see $3x-1$ is a polynomial of degree 1. You can't possible do anything more with it.

Comment: so does that mean 3x - 1 is irreducible?

Comment: Factorization depends on the context: for example the constant polynomial $1$ is not irrecucible on $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ since $(2x+1)^2=1$. In which ring $R$ are you working?

Comment: @RobertThompson From Wikipedia - ' In mathematics, an irreducible polynomial is, roughly speaking, a non-constant polynomial that cannot be factored into the product of two non-constant polynomials.' Consider a polynomial of degree 1. You cannot factor it into two non-constant polynomials. If we want two factor it we may possibly do it with two algebraic expressions of degree $1/2$. You may see that I have used the word algebraic expressions as polynomials have only non negative **integer** exponents.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout working in Z[x]

Comment: Yes, in $Z[x]$ the polynomial $3x-1$ is irreducible.

Comment: @Crostul thank you, what would be my justification of this?

Comment: Write $3x-1 = ab$. Then, one of the factors has degree 0, while the other has degree 1. Let $a$ be the one of degree 0 (i.e. $a \in \Bbb{Z}$), and write $b=Ax+B$, with $A,B \in \Bbb{Z}$. Then $3x-1=aAx+Ba$: this implies that $Ba=1$, so that $a$ is a unit.

Comment: @Crostul thank you this is very helpful